# Illogical SQL out of range value for integer column

Tags: mysql, sql, outofrangeexception

I am getting an odd SQL error. I have a table client which contains the following attributes:

- ClientID
- Title
- Name
- LastName
- Email
- Cellphone
- Points
- Balance

Points is set up as an integer of length 11 with NULL values accepted

I try to insert a new client using the following code:

```
INSERT into client VALUES (154,"Mr","Ted","Jones","td@gmail.com","07951234567",0,0);
```

And I get the following error:

> 1264 - Out of range value for column 'Points' at row 1

Just in case it is needed, the data in the first row is:

```
111 Mr  Rob Taylor  rt@hotmail.com  07523363535 438 0
```

I am finding it hard to understand what the error is about. It's not as if points will ever get to be so large that it needs to become a BigInt.

```
CREATE TABLE client ( 
    ClientID int(11) NOT NULL, 
    Title varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
    Name varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
    LastName varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
    Email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    Cellphone bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Points int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Balance decimal(10,0) NOT NULL 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: you should always specify your columns for an insert statement

Comment: give us the output of "show create table client" so we can see the column structure. Or the create table statement you used.

Comment: I suspect you have some kind of constraint on the Points column, which does not allow 0 value. Check if there are not constrains and/or triggers which can reject this value.

Comment: My apologies. This is the structure of the table:CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `ClientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,`Cellphone` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,

 `Points` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Balance` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: What DBMS is this?  this kind of thing varies widely.

Comment: edit the question with this information please, it is not really useful as a comment

Comment: cell phone shouldn't be an integer, it can start with 0 and more closely resembles a string than a number

Comment: You say the data in your first row has a telephone number starting with a zero. That should be impossible in a bigint. Are you sure you're even looking at the right database?

Comment: how does a `bigint(11)` and `int(11)` differ?  I'm not used to seeing lengths to go along with integer/biginteger types

Comment: I am using MySQL on PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: works fine in a fiddle (though you should still specify columns in an insert) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19d46/1

Comment: "07951234567" is not a legal value for cellphone -- this is the problem.

Comment: Your code (and Gordon's code in his answer) work fine against MySQL with your table. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @Hogan "07951234567" will be converted to the integer 7951234567 and stores just fine. No errors are thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Always specify the columns when using `insert`.  Presumably you intend:

```
INSERT into client(ClientId, Title, Name, LastName, email, Cellphone, Points, Balance)
    VALUES (154, 'Mr', 'Ted', 'Jones', 'td@gmail.com', '07951234567', 0, 0);
```

My first guess is that the columns are in a different order in the table -- but don't bother figuring that out, just be explicit about the columns you are using.

Another possibility is that the cell phone column is declared as some sort of numeric value.  If that is the case, fix the data and change the column to a varchar!

Comment: I tried this earlier before posting the question, but still got the same issue. It is baffling!

Comment: Looks like `Cellphone bigint(11) ` but then why say error is on `Point` ?

Comment: your value of "07951234567" would overflow an int (Point), but not a bigint (cellphone)... it has to have something to do with your column order.

Comment: You are all absolutely right. PHPMyAdmin gives you the ability to drag the columns around and change the order which I did for some reason last week. However, it must store the original order somewhere which is why I was getting this error. I dropped the table and created it from scratch. I then ran the SQL insert code as before and now it works! Thank you so much for your help.